# ContentEditable - Get current font color/size

Tags: javascript, text, editor, contenteditable, font-size

I'm working on Rich Text Editor for web browser and I want to work with values of current font color and size in the RTE/ContentEditable element. Is there some preselected function to get these values, like execCommand, which is connected directly with ContentEditable element? Or should I use some text range jQuery library which will get these properties?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `document.queryCommandValue()` to get the colour and font size of the current selection in all major browsers:

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/AJBsY/

Code:

```
var colour = document.queryCommandValue("ForeColor");
var fontSize = document.queryCommandValue("FontSize");
```

However, the results are inconsistent across browsers and the `FontSize` command only works with font sizes 1-7 used in the HTML `<font>` element rather than CSS, so you'd be better off getting hold of the element containing the selection and examining its CSS properties using `window.getComputedStyle()` / `currentStyle`:

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/K4n2j/

Code:

```
function getComputedStyleProperty(el, propName) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(el, null)[propName];
    } else if (el.currentStyle) {
        return el.currentStyle[propName];
    }
}

function reportColourAndFontSize() {
    var containerEl, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            containerEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            // Make sure we have an element rather than a text node
            if (containerEl.nodeType == 3) {
                containerEl = containerEl.parentNode;
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        containerEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }

    if (containerEl) {
        var fontSize = getComputedStyleProperty(containerEl, "fontSize");
        var colour = getComputedStyleProperty(containerEl, "color");
        alert("Colour: " + colour + ", font size: " + fontSize);
    }
}
```

This is an improvement, but there are still browser inconsistencies such as differing units or colour formats.

Comment: I didn't notice some problems with units in font-size property in new versions of all browsers and IE7,8 as well. However the colour is somewhere interpretated with rgb and somewhere with hex notation. But that's not a problem for me yet, probably I will create some condition for it. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to get "undefined" if the selection contains more than one font-size (or color)? Now when I select all, it alerts "Colour: rgb(0, 0, 0), font size: 16px". This is confusing for my purpose.

Comment: @Timo: It's possible the selection's parent element is not what you think it is. When you select all, it's likely to be he contenteditable element, which may not have any styling.

Comment: I'm trying to traverse all (child and grandchild) nodes of contenteditable div and test `if(sel.containsNode(node, true))` and if it is true, then get the computedstyle of the node and add the font-sizes and colors counter. After traversing, the counters tell are there multiple font-sizes or colors in the selection. Seems to work.