# How to find selected text font size and name on a execCommand WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, execcommand

I am making a WYSIWYG editor using `execCommand()` and my own drag-and-drop javascript functions.

I want to be able to find the name and size of the selected text if applicable.
How can I do this exactly?

Are there specific functions relating to `execCommand()` to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alert(iFrame.document.queryCommandValue("FontSize"));
```

OR

```
alert(iFrame.document.queryCommandValue("ForeColor"));
```

You can't do it with execCommand, as execCommand only returns true or false based on whether or not it succeeded. However, there are some problems with this apparently. I suggest reading up on

[ContentEditable - Get current font color/size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770008/contenteditable-get-current-font-color-size)

Fore more information